# R: Refer to the chromosome in the evaluation function of rbga.bin

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, rbga

I am trying to use the ***[rbga.bin](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/genalg/html/rbga.bin.html)*** genetic function in R.

I have a dataframe with 40 observations (rows) and 189 metrics (columns). In the evaluation function, I have to run a Principal Component Analysis on both the original dataset and the "chromosome dataset" (i.e., the dataframe with some of the metrics columns - the ones that have 1s in the chromosome) in order to produce the fitness score.

For example, a possible solution (chromosome) is the following:

(1,1,1,0,0,...,0)

The solution dataset that I would want to run a PCA on, would just have only the first 3 columns of the original dataset.

How can I refer to that "reduced" dataset inside the evaluation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable you provide to the evaluation function is the chromosome, i.e. the binary vector. You can get the reduced dataset the following way.

Assume `chromosome` is the binary vector, original is the starting dataframe and reduced is the resulting dataframe with only the columns that are 1 in the chromosome.

```
reduced = !!chromosome
reduced = original[reduced]
```

Comment: Downvote for answering a question that should have been closed as unsuitable for SO. Maybe this sort of thing is ontopic for the SE BioInformatics forum.

Comment: SO is full with R questions, which this one is as well. It's 100% a code question.

Comment: It didn't have any R code in it, no library calls to identify the non-base packages that you were or intended to use, and no test data.